# Google Sign-in error inside my flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, google-signin, flutter-test

after login with google sign-in inside my flutter project, why my app data from database storage is not loading, why?
After pressing the google signing button it's logging in, but after login, the data from the database is not loading. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkTQZ.png)

Comment: It can be helpful if you share you app structure. We don't know what you are using provider bloc etc.  Maybe you are lost data when logged in or you should change the login structure.

Comment: hey Ankita first of all a very warm welcome to stackoverflow, your question is very unclear, please add the code snipped. for more details on how to ask a question on this platform please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask